# How to change the background color in android app/ for large screen?

Tags: android, listview, background, android-listview

I have a problem. I want to set the background color of my listview to white, but only the background color of the rows changes. How can I make the background fill the entire screen? Here is my code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_view, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/chalkboardse.ttc");
    textView.setTypeface(tf);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.background);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    return rowView;
}
}
```

Here is my xml file for the list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/background" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the corresponding activity:

```
public class AreaChooser extends ListActivity {

static final String [] FRUIT = new String [] { "Apple", "Pear"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, FRUIT));

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the background of your listview's rows, not the background of the listview itself.

In your `ListActivity` simply do :

```
getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: and what is "listview"? where do i define it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `LinearLayout` needs to be set to fill_parent or match_parent in `R.layout.list_view` 's xml.

Comment: okay, post your xml for list_view, my original answer assumes linearlayout is the only view in question here